# Doctrine can't find a connection after Zend Framework redirect

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I have some troubles with Doctrine integration into ZF.

After simple redirect

```
$this->redirector->setGotoSimple("asd");
```

Doctrine returns

> Doctrine_Connection_Exception: There is no open connection in /Users/insight/Sites/max/library/Doctrine/Manager.php  on line 657

if i try to get this "asd" page directly or press f5 at the error page it loads normally with no error. why so?

Comment: I have no errors if use $this-_forward()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the mistake. You should not to start session before DoctrineInit in the bootstrap, otherwise, it overrides your serialization data in the Doctrine.